# Using 'Dig' to zone transfer but gets a 'timed out connection'

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, timeout, dig

i am corrently trying to test a zone transfer via dig (9.8.4) with the following command:

```
dig axfr @ns.server.com domainname.com
```

and i get the following error:(notice its not a declined zone transfer error)

```
<<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> axfr @ns12.zoneedit.com zonetransfer.me
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

if i query the server without any attr i am getting a respone.

```
e.g  dig ns.server.com domainname.com
```

Comment: Do you get a response if you leave out all options, e.g. `dig @ns.server.com domainname.com`?

Comment: yes i get the following respone:

Comment: yes ( cant post the resault, too long)

Comment: It's best to edit additional information like that into the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Zone transfers rarely fit within a 512 byte UDP reply packet. Most programs implicitly switch over to using TCP when a zone transfer is requested, and `dig` is one of them: the `+tcp` option is implicitly set. The most likely scenario is that your firewall is passing UDP traffic on port 53 but not TCP traffic.

Comment: can i increase the amounts of bytes of a UDP reply packet?
if not, the only solution is to allow TCP traffic on port 53?

Comment: You need to open TCP 53 regardless. Software *expects* to be able to use TCP fallback when they receive truncated UDP replies. There is a standard for larger reply packets over UDP (EDNS0 extensions), but it is not supported by everything.